# Is it not possible to use "Analyze" with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode6

Previously with objective-c code, I could "Analyze" - CMD + Shift + B and Xcode would warn me of all kinds of wrongdoings on my part.

It seems that with Swift, I can do no wrong! No warnings of any kind! But clearly there is a memory leak in my code.

Is there some setting I have to enable to get Swift to analyze my code properly? (I am aware I should use the profiler and test on an actual device, which I do, but I wonder why "Analyze" doesn't do anything.

Comment: Note that Swift is fairly recent, so the static analyzer most likely doesn't know *how* to analyze the code.

Comment: I agree - it (Clang) probably doesn't know how to analyze Swift code yet. But it would still be nice if the analyzer generated a warning of some sort indicating that it's not available. *Currently* in my Swift project, I don't know if the analyzer just isn't running, or if I wrote fantastic code the first time around.

Comment: To be honest, I think that most of the things *Analyze* does for Objective-C, Swift compiler already does during normal compilation. The nice thing about Swift is that it is simpler than C or Obj-C, it has strong types and memory handling has been hidden to the internals, therefore Analysis is much simpler to do.

Comment: I think that the majority of issues detected by the code analyzer in Obj-C, are for the most part prevented by the actual Swift language. were

Comment: It's gain a new complexity after add new functionality like async/await :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Even many releases later, the latest version of XCode (6.4) still cannot do Swift analysis. The 'Analyze' option only works for the Objective C files in your project.

Let's hope the next version will have it, along with the refactoring capabilities which also are still limited to Objective C code.

Comment: XCode 11.2, still nothing. It is seriously infuriating to not have some basic static analyzer...

Comment: Xcode 14.3, still nothing :)

Answer (score 5):

To this moment (Xcode 8.3.x) Static Code analysis skips Swift code. Some Swift warnings cover some of the issues previously detected by the analyzer.

Also the upcoming Xcode 9 (presented in WWDC 2017) does not announce any change in this direction.

Many issues detected by the static Analyzer of Obj-C are for the most part **prevented** by the actual Swift language (e.g. unintended fall-through in switch statements). Other issues and scenarios formerly caught by the analyser, are now caught directly by the Swift compiler.

Many flows and scenarios leading to program crash - (e.g. accessing null pointers, leaving dangling pointers, or accessing released memory blocks) are hardly possible in Swift. Swift strong typing, heavy use of optionals, the requirement to completely cover protocols, and switch-case over enums, etc. remove another bunch of issues previously found by the analyzer.

A Swift static code analyzer will need to go to another level in analyzing program logic, which is much harder, and theoretically impossible to do completely.

So - although I'm quite thrilled to think of some future Xcode Analyzer, I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for it

Answer (score -1):

Update:

As more and more people are down voting my post, just small update from my side. It seems that indeed apple just did allow for pressing option "Analyze" but in the background it does nothing (state for 2016.04.21, though I am not working on iOS for the moment and probably I don't have the latest version of Xcode).

below my original post:

---

Just for next readers of this article. At this moment Xcode 7 is already able to analyze also Swift projects. Refactoring is still not working though.

BR,
Darek

Comment: The analyze button is enabled in Xcode 7 *but* it won't analyze any Swift code.