# Xcode 11.4 Analyze shows no issues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

I was using Xcode "Product > Analyze" to find the localizability issue, but in Xcode 11.4, after analyzing, Xcode shows no issue at all. But I'm certain that there are quite a few issues out there.

I tried to set "Analyze During 'Build'" to YES, but nothing changed

I'm using Xcode 11.4 and swift 5.0

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Alternatively, check this post,  this will show an error message in the console.
https://medium.com/@pinmadhon/finding-non-nslocalized-strings-in-xcode-8-in-swift-3-or-objc-589ee279a166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what you think you mean by “localizability issue,” but this much is certain: you’re barking up the wrong tree. Xcode’s Analyze feature is for Objective-C only. In Swift it does nothing! If you want to trace issues with your code, just compile it. If your code doesn’t have any compile time issues, then you need to use the various scheme based runtime tools, UI testing, and so forth, to track down whatever you think is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, If anyone has the same issue, please check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326036/is-it-not-possible-to-use-analyze-with-swift) to see detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the build device you've selected isn't "Any iOS device". That gives no output when using Objective C. Changing it to a simulator device gives the Analysis output.